# Join using same table related to other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day everyone. I came across the following problem, I'm changing some selects that used an old T-SQL formatting, as in the example below.:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 M,
     TABLE2 A,
     TABLE3 TP
WHERE M.CODIGO1 *= A.CODIGO1
      AND  
      M.CODIGO1 *= TP.CODIGO2
```

And when making the change to be able to use Join in FROM, I came across the following problem, as I already perform the join in .:

```sql
TABLE1 M LEFT JOIN TABLE2 A ON M.CODIGO1 = A.CODIGO1
```

How could I rerelated table TABLE1 using LEFT JOIN?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Edited question.

Comment: *"How could I rerelated table TABLE1 using LEFT JOIN?"* What does this mean? It doesn't make sense. Also, the above SQL isn't valid; you're missing an `AND` or `OR` and object `Table 2` needs to be delimit identified, as it contains white space in its name.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu there was a syntax error, this type of syntax was used in SQL Server 2000 and earlier versions, that's why it's that way.

Comment: Even SQL Server 2000 required `AND` and `OR` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Though you haven't explained the sentence I asked you for. What are you *actually* asking here?

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain better, I would like to use JOIN again in the TABaLE1 table, but as I have already done a previous JOIN, how could I do it in a more elegant way in the code?

Comment: You aren't `JOIN`ing to `table1`, you're joining to `Table 2`and `Table 3`. Are you just trying to replace the 1980's syntax with the 1992 syntax? You just need to use 2 `LEFT JOIN`s then.

Comment: @Larnu That's correct, but in the legacy code we have as in this example, in the clause WHERE this join using the same table, how could it replace ?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN TABLE2 A ON M.CODIGO1 = A.CODIGO1 LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON M.CODIGO2 = TP.CODIGO2`. I really suggest reading some articles/tutorials. The ANSI-92 syntax has been around for 29 years, and `JOIN` syntax is fundamental to writing any SQL.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your kind of "playful" response, I could see where I should go, even at 29 years of syntax. Good luck man, humble takes us far, good morning.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ancient comma-join syntax, which was replaced in by ANSI in SQL-92, back in 1992.

This is the equivalent of the more modern syntax using sequential `LEFT JOIN`s

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 M
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 A ON M.CODIGO1 = A.CODIGO1
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 TP ON M.CODIGO2 = TP.CODIGO2;
```